# counting of characters in c programming language using getchar() to get input character

Tags: c, while-loop, char, newline, getchar

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main()
    {
    
        int num=0,ch='9';
    
        while((ch=getchar())!=EOF){
            ++num;
        }
        printf("\n%d",num);
    }

/* this is a program to count no of characters entered using getchar().
```

suppose i entered

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

answer displayed is 10 not 5

*/[image]

Comment: How do you define a character? You are counting bytes not characters. A `char` in C has nothing to do with a character. How many characters should it count for this sequences?: `a`, ` `, ,.-?`, `\t` (tabulator), `\n` (newline), `ä`, `€`, `µ`, `房`, `집` (note that this are 3 smaller letters combined to 1 bigger letter. Sorry, don't know the correct terms for this, i don't understand korean), ``, `` (note that this is a combination of mulitple unicode code points), `Aͤ`, ... ? What should it do when the input is not valid unicode (assuming UTF8)?

Comment: And how many characters is this:`h̶̢̨͇͓̼̤͎̣̝͖̳̫̋͛̏̑̃́̾̐́͊̆̋͘͘͜͝͝`? 1? 33 (number of code points)? Your program would count 62.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getchar` reads any character including white space characters as for example the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter as demonstrated by the output of your program

If you want to skip white space characters you can write for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    size_t num = 0;
    int ch;

    while ( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF )
    {
        if ( !isspace( ch ) ) ++num;
    }

    printf( "\num = %zu\n", num );
}
```

If you want to skip only new line characters then the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    size_t num = 0;
    int ch;

    while ( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF )
    {
        if ( ch != '\n' ) ++num;
    }

    printf( "\num = %zu\n", num );
}
```

An alternative approach is to use another standard function `scanf` as for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    size_t num = 0;
    char ch;

    while ( scanf( " %c", &ch ) == 1 )
    {
        ++num;
    }

    printf( "\num = %zu\n", num );
}
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format specification

```
scanf( " %c", &ch )
       ^^^
```

It allows to skip white space characters.

Comment: but how is it possible for getchar() to receive two characters, even if it is possible, but only initial value is taken

Comment: @DeveshKumar As I wrote in the answer getchar reads the typed by you character and the new line character that corresponds to the pressed key Enter. When you press the Enter key the system places the new line character '\n' in the input buffer as any typed character.

Comment: sorry to bother u...i am just trying to understand. It means for each input, loop is repeated two times.

Comment: @DeveshKumar The loop is repeated as many times as there is a character in the input buffer. Pressing the Enter key places the new line character in the input buffer.

Comment: A character does necessarly not need exactly `char`. In UTF-8 the character `ä` needs 2 chars (assuming `CHAR_BIT==8`). It will get really complicated when you want to count characters and you first have to define a character (which is already hard).